# Nest API incomplete data

Tags: nest-api

I am using the REST API for the Nest themostat, and I seem to be getting incomplete data from the Nest servers.  The names of some of the thermostats are missing (and the word "Thermostat" is in the place of the names), and the away temperature target temperature of the thermostats is also missing.  Following is the JSON returned from a GET HTTP request.  Has anyone else seen this?

```html
{  
   "devices":{  
      "thermostats":{  
         "vMVMwQjG5n9k6fK8shB1it40C6OIbcTY":{  
            "humidity":40,
            "device_id":"vMVMwQjG5n9k6fK8shB1it40C6OIbcTY",
            "ambient_temperature_c":23.5,
            "ambient_temperature_f":74,
            "structure_id":"wbF3Bg291lfTwr7L3QiSKtxJuEvVByOwG5G_f4KpKW4VCe_3KzC6XA",
            "name":"Thermostat",
            "name_long":"Thermostat",
            "is_online":true
         },
         "vMVMwQjG5n-_ES9UeSTCm940C6OIbcTY":{  
            "humidity":55,
            "device_id":"vMVMwQjG5n-_ES9UeSTCm940C6OIbcTY",
            "ambient_temperature_c":17.0,
            "ambient_temperature_f":63,
            "structure_id":"wbF3Bg291lfTwr7L3QiSKtxJuEvVByOwG5G_f4KpKW4VCe_3KzC6XA",
            "name":"Thermostat",
            "name_long":"Thermostat",
            "is_online":true
         },
         "vMVMwQjG5n-n3KHstCHhCN40C6OIbcTY":{  
            "humidity":40,
            "device_id":"vMVMwQjG5n-n3KHstCHhCN40C6OIbcTY",
            "target_temperature_c":22.5,
            "target_temperature_f":73,
            "ambient_temperature_c":25.5,
            "ambient_temperature_f":78,
            "structure_id":"wbF3Bg291lfTwr7L3QiSKtxJuEvVByOwG5G_f4KpKW4VCe_3KzC6XA",
            "name":"Thermostat",
            "name_long":"Thermostat",
            "is_online":true
         },
         "vMVMwQjG5n8AytjfXztxst40C6OIbcTY":{  
            "humidity":45,
            "device_id":"vMVMwQjG5n8AytjfXztxst40C6OIbcTY",
            "ambient_temperature_c":24.0,
            "ambient_temperature_f":75,
            "structure_id":"wbF3Bg291lfTwr7L3QiSKtxJuEvVByOwG5G_f4KpKW4VCe_3KzC6XA",
            "name":"Master Bedroom",
            "name_long":"Master Bedroom Thermostat",
            "is_online":true
         },
         "vMVMwQjG5n8P8TeDkZXGBd40C6OIbcTY":{  
            "humidity":55,
            "locale":"en-US",
            "temperature_scale":"F",
            "is_using_emergency_heat":false,
            "has_fan":false,
            "software_version":"4.3.1",
            "has_leaf":false,
            "device_id":"vMVMwQjG5n8P8TeDkZXGBd40C6OIbcTY",
            "name":"Downstairs",
            "can_heat":true,
            "can_cool":true,
            "hvac_mode":"heat",
            "target_temperature_c":24.0,
            "target_temperature_f":76,
            "target_temperature_high_c":24.0,
            "target_temperature_high_f":75,
            "target_temperature_low_c":20.0,
            "target_temperature_low_f":68,
            "ambient_temperature_c":24.0,
            "ambient_temperature_f":75,
            "away_temperature_high_c":24.0,
            "away_temperature_high_f":76,
            "away_temperature_low_c":12.5,
            "away_temperature_low_f":55,
            "structure_id":"wbF3Bg291lfTwr7L3QiSKtxJuEvVByOwG5G_f4KpKW4VCe_3KzC6XA",
            "fan_timer_active":false,
            "name_long":"Downstairs Thermostat",
            "is_online":true
         }
      }
   },
   "structures":{  
      "wbF3Bg291lfTwr7L3QiSKtxJuEvVByOwG5G_f4KpKW4VCe_3KzC6XA":{  
         "smoke_co_alarms":[  
            "JJcqUcVH2RV_Ung1pBneG940C6OIbcTY"
         ],
         "name":"Home",
         "away":"home",
         "thermostats":[  
            "vMVMwQjG5n-_ES9UeSTCm940C6OIbcTY",
            "vMVMwQjG5n8P8TeDkZXGBd40C6OIbcTY",
            "vMVMwQjG5n9k6fK8shB1it40C6OIbcTY",
            "vMVMwQjG5n-n3KHstCHhCN40C6OIbcTY",
            "vMVMwQjG5n8AytjfXztxst40C6OIbcTY"
         ],
         "structure_id":"wbF3Bg291lfTwr7L3QiSKtxJuEvVByOwG5G_f4KpKW4VCe_3KzC6XA"
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have names for two (Downstairs Thermostat, Master Bedroom Thermostat) of the five thermostats in your list.  I would guess no specific name was defined when the thermostat was set up at Nest.com. 
The away setting is in a different portion of the api, under the structures data element. The theory being, if you're away, it would impact all of your thermostats.

Comment: I see the away setting under structure.  Thanks!  As for the name not showing up, I think that might be because I created the thermostats using the Nest Chrome plugin.  The Nest Chrome plugin automatically creates locations for new thermostats.  The names were showing up in the web app, but they were not showing up in the JSON returned from the REST API.  However, the names did start to show up once I changed the location of the thermostat in the web app.  It is as if the database used for the REST API did not get populated with data until I set the thermostat location.  All is working now.